# Retrieve all chained task result by id separately in Celery

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I'm trying to retrieve the results of all chained tasks in celery that's stored in the mysql result backend.

For example, I have the following two celery tasks,

```
@celery.task(name='celery_fl.add')
def add(x, y, value=None):
    if value is None:
        try:
            return x + y
        except TypeError:
            return None
    return value

@celery.task(name='celery_fl.mul')
def mul(x, y, value=None):
    if value is None:
        try:
            return x * y
        except TypeError:
            return None
    return value
```

and here is how I chain them,

```
parent = (add.s(2, 2) | mul.s(8)).apply_async()
```

Here the output of parent.get() will be the result of the final chained task. parent.parent.get() will give me the output of the first chained task.

What I'm trying to achieve is that I'd like to get the same output using the task id at a latter stage.

```
task_id = 'bc5fc4b1-613e-4ef0-b5c8-900999d9a6f1'
parent = AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery)
```

say that the task_id I have belongs to the second task in the chained event (the parent). Then I should get the result of the first chained task if I type parent.parent.get(). But somehow I get None as the value. Is there another way I should be getting the task with task_id instead AsyncResult()?

Answer (score 0):

When using a mysql backend to store results, the results of each chained task is stored separately. But the task instance is no longer available and without this it's not possible to retrieve the results of the sub tasks using the main task (Ref - [Celery tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains)).

So in order to retrieve the results of all tasks, the task ID of each task should be stored somewhere in the database.

An example using flask (python),

```
chain = (s3_init.s(order.name, order.id)|create_order_sheet.s(order.id, order.name) | create_order_info.s(order.id, order.name))
res = chain()
process = {
   's3_init': res.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.id,
   'order_sheet': res.parent.parent.parent.parent.id,
   'order_info': res.parent.parent.parent.id
}
order.update(process_id=json.dumps(process))
```

Then you can simply get the task IDs from the database and use celery.result.AsyncResult(task_id) to retrieve each task by ID (ref - [Async results](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html?highlight=AsyncResult#celery.result.AsyncResult)).

Comment: This is a good answer, however how to do the same thing with a group inside the chain for which number of tasks created can be random ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that gets the topmost parent:

```py
from celery import chain, Celery


app = Celery("my-tasks")

@app.task
def run_task(item_id):
    res = chain(
        long_task_1.s(item_id),
        long_task_2.s(),
        long_task_3.s(),
    ).delay()

    while getattr(res, "parent", None):
        res = res.parent

    item = MyItem.objects.get(id=item_id)
    item.celery_root_task_id = res.id
    item.save()

    return res
```

Then, you can retrieve all the children later with:

```py
from celery.result import AsyncResult

root_result = AsyncResult(obj.celery_task_id, app=app)

task_results = ", ".join(
    [
        f"{t._cache.get('task_name')}: {t.status}"
        for t, _ in root_result.collect()
    ]
)
```